# How to automatically graph the output of a shell function

Tags: command-line, bash, graphics, ffmpeg

I do a lot of video editing and processing, and spend a lot of time looking at the output of command line programs like ffmpeg. Ffmpeg produces a regular output of the form

```
frame=1234 fps=80 q=-1.0 size= 23456kB time=1234 bitrate=280.0kbits/s
frame=1237 fps=80 q=-1.0 size= 23678kB time=1258 bitrate=280.0kbits/s
...
```

my question is, is there a command line program that could automatically graph the output of this (preferably live)? so you could write

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.avi -lotsofoptions -outputfile.avi > graphprogramorsomething
```

and it would produce a nice chart showing how the fps and things varied throughout the whole process.

Not really a mission critical request but would make the wait much nicer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the generation being done "automatically", but you can certainly automate it.

Gnuplot might be your best bet.

Here's a [brief tutorial](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/487/plot-your-graphs-with-command-line-gnuplot/).

Here's another method to extract some data from ffmpeg:  http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/291/71

xgraph and ploticus might also be of use.